# Understanding a C prototype

Tags: c, function-prototypes

A function prototype is

`int alt_irq_register (alt_u32 id, 
 void* context, 
 void (*isr)(void*, alt_u32));`

What does the last part mean? What is the `*isr` doing?

Comment: It's a typical function pointer, roughly translates to `void whatever(void*, alt_u32)` - interrupt requests? very low-level, respect.

Comment: Try [`cdecl`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*isr%29%28void*%2C+alt_u32%29).

Comment: @Kerrek: that page helps alot ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pointer to a function. You must use a function as parameter of the `alt_irq_register` function. Example:

```
void irq_handler(void *ptr, alt_u32 val) { /* my function */
    /* I'm handling the interupt */
}
int alt_irq_register (alt_u32 id, void* context, void (*isr)(void*, alt_u32));
```

In your code, you must use `alt_irq_register` function in this way:

```
/* your code */
ret = alt_irq_register(id, context_ptr, irq_handler);
/* other code */
```

I am supposing that this function register and interrupt handler, so during the registration you are passing to the system the function that it must uses when the associated interrupt occur.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pointer to a function. The function takes two arguments (`void*` and `alt_u32`) and returns nothing (`void`). Its parameter name is `isr`.